# How to add and execute a JavaScript function to a web page with Watir

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir

How can I add a JavaScript function to a given webpage, execute it, and then read its results with Watir?

```
require 'watir'
myfn = %<
  function samsFunction () {
    var samsBigVariable;
    window.samsBigVariable = "my secret goes here";
  };
  samsFunction();
>.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto "google.com"
b.execute_script myfn
b.execute_script "window.samsBigVariable"
 => nil
```

Executing the same JavaScript in the console results in the variable being set and returned when called. What is different about `execute_script`?

Comment: Cheers to the folks who downvoted this with no explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly return the value:

```
b.execute_script "return window.samsBigVariable"
#=> "my secret goes here"
```

Comment: OK, that works and I feel a bit silly. Maybe you can help with what I was  ultimately trying to solve for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48208920/1651458