# How to add and execute html2canvas on a webpage with Watir

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir

How can I add a html2canvas to a given webpage, execute it, and then read its results with Watir?

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto "google.com"

path = "/path/to/html2canvas.js" # v. 0.5.0-alpha1
h2c_payload = File.read(path)
b.execute_script h2c_payload

h2c_activator = %<
  function genScreenshot () {
    var canvasImgContentDecoded;
    html2canvas(document.body, {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
       window.canvasImgContentDecoded = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    }});
  };
  genScreenshot();
>.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip
b.execute_script h2c_activator

b.execute_script "return window.canvasImgContentDecoded"
 => nil
```

Executing the same JavaScript in the console results in the variable (eventually) being set and then returned when called. What is different about `execute_script`?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using v0.5.0-alpha1 rather than the latest v1.0.0-alpha.9?

Comment: @JustinKo only because I found an example with that version, and none of the versions seem to be a GM release. I will try changing the version tomorrow.

Comment: Ultimately, 1.0 did not work, but v0.4.1 does. Thanks for flagging this up!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that canvasImgContentDecoded is being checked before the canvas finishes being rendered. Not being a JavaScript programmer, I find it easier to do the waiting in Ruby/Watir instead:

```
result = nil
b.wait_until { result = b.execute_script "return window.canvasImgContentDecoded;" }
p result
#=> "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA..."
```

The above will only fix the problem when using Chrome.

Firefox seems to have other limitation and/or restrictions that prevent the original code from working. The following worked in Firefox and in Chrome. Note that this might require the more current version of html2canvas:

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto("google.com")

# Load html2canvas - currently  v1.0.0-alpha.9
h2c_payload = %<
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src =  'https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js';
  document.head.appendChild(script);
>.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip
b.execute_script(h2c_payload)

# Wait for html2canvas to load
b.wait_while { b.execute_script("return typeof html2canvas === 'undefined'") }

# Generate the canvas
h2c_activator = 'html2canvas(document.body).then(canvas => {window.canvasImgContentDecoded = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");});'
b.execute_script h2c_activator

# Wait for canvas to be created
result = nil
b.wait_until { result = b.execute_script "return window.canvasImgContentDecoded;" }
p result
#=> "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA..."
```

Comment: I get only `Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for true condition on #<Watir::Browser:0x..f8ac5dc61862c6c6e url="https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl" title="Google">`. In console the image is generated within seconds, if not faster.

Comment: Oh interesting. The code works when using Chrome, but not Firefox. That's troublesome.